# Brown thing around Mango leave's veins

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, diseases, leaves, seedlings

My 4 mango plants (from 5 to 8 months) are now struggling with weird disease. It started about 3 weeks ago, lower leaves got brown and finally gone. Now I have noticed brown thing on younger leaves.

[image]

Plants sit in pots, in potting soil, with good light, being watered twice a week. Last month I gave them organic fertilizer (5-5-5), not sure if that could be the cause.

I would be thankful for any hint.

Comment: Try grabbing some tweezers and scraping a bit of it off. Does it come off easy or does it seem to be inside the leaf itself or fused with the leaf itself?

Comment: Hi Rob, it's inside the leaf, can't really scratch it.

Comment: It's hard, for me at least, to tell exactly whats happening. It seems to be a fungal infection of some kind. You might try a fungicide spray, just follow the directions on the bottle.